# Python & Vb.net Console Application print word into 2 lines with up & down

Tags: python, vb.net, console

I want to print my name into 2 lines with up & down in Python Console & Vb.net Console,

Example my name : Dominic Charles
the result of printing is :
D m n c h r e
 o i i C a l s

like above using loop.
I can't figure out the logic of printing this name, anyone can provide me the solution of printing like this?

Comment: Seems like you should iterate through the string. Remove the spaces from your original string, take the first character into a new string and add to the new string every other character.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here **[ask]** and it's also important to look here .. **[mcve]** .. **Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered** and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Comment: Without including your code we have to resort to crystal balls and mine always gets smudged with fingerprints - Include your code please. Thanks :-)